# Django - form_valid() variable undefined

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I need to get the profile_id of the user who is trying to create a Review to store in the model. I can get the attributes for the User as they are built into django but when I try to use what's below to get profile_id I get "prof is not defined" error.

**views.py**

```
    class ReviewCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
      model = Review
      fields = ['rating', 'reviewtext']
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReviewCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['prof'] = Profile.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        return context
      def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.product = self.request.GET.get('pk')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.profile = prof
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators = [MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    reviewtext = models.TextField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: `prof` isn't defined anywhere in that function.  Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: What's the point of having separate links to User and Profile anyway? Those models are already linked.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because Profile has fields that I use elsewhere, I'm only showing the fields which are relevant to my question.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm trying to get it from get_context_data

Comment: Yes but you can always get the profile via the user. There's no need to explicitly link them both to Review.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I understand what you mean now, one of the requirements for the assignment was to have an author (Username)  in Review but I needed the fields in Profile too. Is there still a way to get profile_id in the class above?

Comment: Well you can still get it from `self.request.user.profile`. But as I say there is no reason to. Nevertheless, what you were trying to do had many problems: you didn't call `get_context_data`; if you had, you would have got a dict, not an attribute; the `prof` key of that dict is values list, for some reason, rather than a Profile object anyway.

Comment: I just thought of that and it worked, I came back here to make it an answer. Thanks anyway @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profile links to User by foreign key so I can just write the line below, also product_id was getting a null constraint till I added the self.kwargs line.

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    form.instance.product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.profile = self.request.user.profile
    return super().form_valid(form)
```